# Ruby on Rails Runtime Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

I am trying to find a way to get a rails console for a program during runtime with all instantiated variables. The normal rails console does not have access to any instantiated variables of its respective running application. For example, when a rails application crashes during runtime, a webpage will load with the error listed in red text, a snippet of the code where the error was raised, and a console at the bottom with access to variables instantiated during runtime.

See image below for console im talking about
[image]

The best thing I could find was a gem called pry, which seems to allow you to access a console during runtime by adding the line 'binding.pry' in your code at the point where you want access to the console. I would be fine with this, but seeing as how rails already gives you access to this when your app crashes, I would think there is a "vanilla" way to do this. Unfortunately I can't find anything online about this feature in rails. This seems like such a valuable tool for debugging I can't see why rails doesn't implement this. Is there a better way to debug during runtime? a better gem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will suggest you to use [Better Errors](https://github.com/BetterErrors/better_errors)

Better Errors replaces the standard Rails error page with a much better and more useful error page. It is also usable outside of Rails in any Rack app as Rack middleware.

Comment: Thanks for the response, im going to check out this gem. Do you know if there is a way to open the error page while the program is running fine w.o errors, just to access the console?

Comment: Thanks, web-console works perfectly for what I want.